# Gray descriptive text in a textbox which disappears once clicked

Tags: c#, textbox

I would like the textbox itself to have the words "Insert Description" within the textbox and once the user clicks the textbox to begin typing, "Insert Description" disappears and they are allowed to type their text.

Here is one example of what I'm talking about:
[image]

Notice it has the gray "Search" in the textbox. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What UI technology is this?  WPF, win forms, etc...

Comment: This is called a "watermark" or "placeholder" and depending on the UI Tech you are using, it might be present or not...

Comment: Is it WPF or WinForms?

Comment: [Watermark textbox in C# windows application](http://www.aspdotnet-pools.com/2014/06/watermark-textbox-in-windows.html) May be this link can help you out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void Form_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox.Text = "Place Holder text...";`enter code here`
    }

    private void textBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(textBox.Text == "Place Holder text...")
        {
            textBox.Text = ""
        }
    }

    private void textBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(textBox.Text == "")
        {
            textBox.Text = "Place Holder text..."
        {
    }
```

Textbox does not contains placeholder property so you will have to do it your self like this

Comment: For a full answer you could add changes to textBox.ForeColor.. For adding an icon you would have to show and hide a nested Label, maybe even with the placeholder text.

Answer (score 2):

If WPF try the following:

Cheat by telling XAML you are binding to a property that doesn't exist, then set your placeholder text in the PlaceHolderValue of the property:

```
<TextBox  Name="myTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top"  
                 Text="{Binding Path=fakeproperty, PlaceHolderValue='Insert Description'}"/>
```

Winforms, try this:

```
private const string PLACE_HOLDER_TEXT = "Insert Description";

private void textBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
}

private void textBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text)) textBox1.Text = PLACE_HOLDER_TEXT;
}
```